# Avoid animation of UICollectionView after reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, animation, ios6, uiview, uicollectionview

UICollectionView animate items after reloadItemsAtIndexPaths is called (fade animation).

Is there a way to avoid this animation?

iOS 6

Answer (score 261, accepted):

It's worth noting that if you're targeting iOS 7 and above, you can use the new `UIView` method `performWithoutAnimation:`. I suspect that under the hood this is doing much the same as the other answers here (temporarily disabling `UIView` animations / Core Animation actions), but the syntax is nice and clean.

So for this question in particular...

**Objective-C:**

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
}];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
}
```

Of course this principle can be applied for any situation that you want to ensure a change is ***not*** animated.

Comment: This worked better than the accepted answer for me on iOS 7+.

Comment: It disables all the animations not only for collection view

Comment: @user2159978 That's correct; all the answers here temporarily disable UIView animations. The animations are only disabled for actions initiated from within the passed-in block, in this case just the collection view's reload. It is a perfectly valid answer to the question being asked, so I don't think it deserves a down vote.

Comment: Incredible solution. Using this instead of animateWithDuration:0 prevents a quick but visible layout glitch when using self-sizing collection view cells with no itemSize

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore on iOS 14, inside this block I use reloadData, but with iOS 13 it worked

Comment: Seems to work on iOS 17 if you add collectionView.layoutIfNeeded() inside UIView.performWithoutAnimation { ... }.

Answer (score 164):

You could also try this:

```
UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

...

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}];
```

### Edit:

I have also found that if you wrap `performBatchUpdates` in a UIView animation block, the UIView animation is used instead of the default animation, so you can just set the animation duration to 0, like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

This is extra cool if you want to use iOS 7 springy animations during inserts and deletes!

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful in adding stopwatch timers to uicollectionview cells.

Comment: Brilliant! I used this with insertCells, and with the keyboard up, to animate the collectionView to a new offset after the cell was inserted.

Comment: conflicts with other animations :/

Comment: As Peter says, this interferes with other animations. Instead, you should call [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES] outside of the completion block. That way you only prevent that 1 animation.

Comment: I added an alternative method, which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Wrapping ```performBatchUpdates``` inside ```animateWithDuration``` is brilliant! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: WARNING. This method DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY!!! Try to scroll while this method is executed. At least in my case when I should reload layout too it breaks content size of collection view

Comment: I don't know why but it's perfectly fix my flashing issue with UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations. Thank you very much.

Comment: Second one is much safer! :)

Comment: Visually, the second method does not work as well as the first method.

Answer (score 22):

> UICollectionView animate items after reloadItemsAtIndexPaths is called
>   (fade animation).
>
> Is there a way to avoid this animation?
>
> iOS 6

I assume you're using a FlowLayout.  Since you're trying to get rid of the fade animation, try this:

```
import UIKit

class NoFadeFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attrs?.alpha = 1.0
        return attrs
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attrs?.alpha = 1.0
        return attrs
    }

}
```

This is a very old question, so you're probably not targeting iOS 6 anymore.  I was personally working on tvOS 11 and had the same question, so this is here for anyone who comes along with the same problem.

Comment: There were 3 or 4 comments on this answer to the effect of "Wow this works really well!"  Someone decided to remove the comments.  I think, factually, this is the modern and non-hacky way of accomplishing this, and those comments were a recognition of this.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a [category on UICollectionView](https://gist.github.com/4571986) to do just that. The trick is to disable all animations while reloading:

```
if (!animated) {
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
}

[self reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];

if (!animated) {
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: I also get response from Apple that this should not do any animation, if so it's a bug. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug.

Comment: You can also just do `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)` as a shorthand for this.

Answer (score 7):

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func reloadWithoutAnimation(){
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
        self.reloadData()
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: this is swift 3 syntax

Comment: this worked good, even better than UIView.performWithoutAnimation

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Swift 3 version to `performBatchUpdates` without animation to a `UICollectionView`. I found this to work better for me than `collectionView.reloadData()` because it reduced cell swapping when records were inserted.

```
func appendCollectionView(numberOfItems count: Int){

        // calculate indexes for the items to be added
        let firstIndex = dataItems.count - count
        let lastIndex = dataItems.count - 1

        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        for index in firstIndex...lastIndex {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }

   UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)reloadCollectionViewAnimated:(BOOL)animated  {

    if (animated) {
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    } else {
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
        [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
        [CATransaction commit];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my $0.02, I tried both versions of the selected answer, and the original way worked better for my purposes. I am working on an infinite scrolling calendar view that allows for a user to enter the calendar at a given week and then swipe back and forth and select individual days for filtering a list.

In my implementation, in order to keep things performant on older devices the array of dates that represent the calendar view has to be kept relatively small which means holding about 5 weeks worth of dates, with the user in the middle at the 3rd week. The issue with using the second approach is, there's a second step where you have to scroll the collection view back to the middle without an animation, which makes for a very jagged appearance for some reason with the blocked base animation.

My Code:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathDeleteArray];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathAddArray];

} completion:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:14 inSection:0];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func reloadRowsWithoutAnimation(at indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        let contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
        }
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        collectionView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `reloadData()` try the following to reload all visible cells without animation.

```
self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
```