# UICollectionView custom animation

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I change the height of a `UICollectionViewCell` if a user touches it. To achieve that I use `performBatchUpdates:`to animate the height change. This works perfectly and the change gets animated with a standard grow and shrink animation.

But I would like to change this standard animation. How would I do that? I can't seem to find any hint on how to influence the animation type used.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the hint here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15068865/956433 it is possible to wrap the `performBatchUpdates:` into a `UIView` animation block. So to change the standard grow and shrink animation to a more fancy spring animation you could implement the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
      initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                     [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                         // your changes to the data
                     } completion:nil];
                 } completion:nil];
```