# why it seems so slow when updating collection view using reloadItems at IndexPath method?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

so usually I use `collectionView.reloadData()` to update all data available, it will reload data in all the cells. But I need to update only particular cell on my collection view, so I use `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [selectedIndexPath])`

but it seems so slow like the gif file in here: http://g.recordit.co/3z14J3bR7X.gif

as you can see, the thumb icon seems as if have 'animation' with duration 0.2s, it seems slow, even though I don't have it on my code. I want to get rid of that 'animation effect' if I use `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [selectedIndexPath])`

If I change using `collectionView.reloadData()` that 'animation effect' does not appear, but for some reasons, I can't use `collectionView.reloadData()`

so, how to solve this issue, why this happen ?

Comment: Use dispatch main queue

Comment: Hmmm... have you tried wrapping your call to `reloadItems(at:)` inside a `UIView.performWithAnimation` closure, as in the following answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403881/988260

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler thanks, yes, thats the answer. using  'UIView.performWithAnimation'

Comment: Oh okay cool. I'll mark this as a duplicate of that question then. 